# I'm trying to override a style in an id with a class and it's not working. What m I doing wrong?

Tags: css

I use the header id on many pages but don't want the bottom border to show on only certain pages. The code below has a bunch of the styles stripped from the header ID just to keep it simple:

```
#header {
width:790px;
min-height:230px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #DADADA;
}

.header-no-line {
border-bottom: none;    
}

<div Id="header" class="header-no-line">
<h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is with CSS specificity: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

You can just add the `important` keyword to fix this issue in your case:

```
.header-no-line {
    border-bottom: none !important; /* <-----  */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should read up about specificity. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ is a good article.

A good rule is:

> “Start at 0, add 1000 for style attribute, add 100 for each ID, add 10
>   for each attribute, class or pseudo-class, add 1 for each element name
>   or pseudo-element.”

In this case, the ID is worth 100, and the class is worth 10, so the ID wins.

Also, anytime you are 'undoing' CSS, then it's usually a bad sign.

The rubbish way to fix this is to add an `!important` to that declaration, but most people would pick that up in a code review and ask why it was needed – it rarely is the way to do things.

Many people also suggest never using IDs for CSS, and instead using classes for everything (well, other than normal selectors etc), and only using IDs for Javascript hooks. That's quite a good way to go about things.

Answer (score 0):

The more specific you are in css the more important the more important your rule is.

for example:

instead of `.header-no-line` you could use

```
#header .header-no-line { border-bottom:none; }
```

or

```
body #header .header-no-line { border-bottom:none; }
```

also as mentioned using the `!important` attribute should probably do the trick.

`#header .header-no-line { border-bottom:none !important; }`

**UPDATE:** I completely missed that `.header-no-line` was not a child of `#header`... my above code wont work. But this will:

`body .header-no-line { border-bottom:none !important; }`

Comment: `.header-no-line` is not a descendant of `#header`.

Comment: you're right, I completely did not notice that. Thanks for pointing that out.